# If $f$ is differentiable in $\Bbb R$ such that $f(\frac{2}{3}) = 25$ and $f'(\frac{2}{3}) = 45$. Find $h'(2)$ if $h$ is known in function of $f$.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

If $f$ is differentiable in $\Bbb R$ such that $f(\frac{2}{3}) = 25$ and $f'(\frac{2}{3}) = 45$. If $h(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1} \cdot f\left( \frac{x}{x+1}\right)$, find $h'(2)$

After using the product rule and replacing the value in $h'(x)$ I found that the answer is $15$, but apparently this is wrong. The correct answer is $-1$ because we need to apply the chain rule in $f'\left( \frac{x}{x+1}\right)$. My question is why we can't just replace with $2$ getting $f'(\frac{2}{3})$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a step back.  When you did the product rule, one of the terms will have the factor
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(f\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\right)$$
This is the stage at which you need to use the chain rule.  It's incorrect to simply put a prime on the $f.$  The correct application of the derivative (via the chain rule) gives
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(f\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\right) = f'\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}[rcl]
$
h(x) & =&\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}\cdot f\bigg(\dfrac{x}{x+1}\bigg) \\
h'(x) & = & \dfrac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\cdot f\bigg(\dfrac{x}{x+1}\bigg)+f'\bigg(\dfrac{x}{x+1}\bigg)\cdot\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}\cdot\dfrac{x}{x^2+1} \\
h'(2) & = & -\dfrac{3}{25}\cdot f(\dfrac{2}{3}) + f'(\dfrac{2}{3})\cdot \dfrac{1}{9} \cdot \dfrac{2}{5} \\
& = &-\dfrac{3}{25}\cdot 25 + 45\cdot \dfrac{1}{9} \cdot \dfrac{2}{5} \\
& = &-3+2 \\
& = & -1 \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$h'(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}f\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)+\frac{x}{(x^2+1)(x+1)^2}f'\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your hint! Just corrected!